# HTML5 video after FFmpeg compress set currentTime behavior defferent in browsers

Tags: video, ffmpeg

i have a mp4 video([oceans.mp4](http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4)), and i use ffmpeg compress it`ffmpeg -i oceans.mp4 output.mp4`(output.mp4).

then i open the origin in the chrome and safari, in the console, i write:

```
var video = document.querySelector('video')
video.currentTime = 4.68
```

the video locate the same frame(at least looks the same)

but i open the output, it looks different!

so i do many test:

1. it might be the broswers difference?
   may be not. the origin video looks totally the same
2. it might be the some props of video?
   i use `ffprobe -show_streams -select_streams v:0  output.mp4`to show and compare two videos, only has_b_frames(0 and 2) and bitrates are different
3. it might be had_b_frames?
   `ffmpeg -i oceans.mp4 -bf 0 output.mp4`
   then i use the command to set it to 0, but it do not work...(sad
4. it might be the ffmpeg's error!(i have no idea...)

   `ffmpeg -i oceans.mp4 -vcodec copy -an output_file.mp4`
   i use the command only get video but delete audio...the video is corrent

so i have no idea why the video show different... please help me

Comment: Show the full log of your FFmpeg command.  This could be for many reasons.  Also, is it actually a problem for you?  What issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Brad
i have a situation, if the video play end, show the last frame, and the video can be cut by user，so in chrome and safari，at the same currentTIme, it shows different...

and the full log of FFmpeg command..is too many, i contrast carefully，and the result i description above

Comment: The video tag is not required to be frame accurate. What you are trying to achieve just may not be possible without a significantly more complex solution.